# Deleting a row from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to delete a row from an SQL table where a row contains the user Id and the column bookingComplete is = to 'No'. However it doesn't seem to be deleting the row. Does anyone know why?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                $user = $_SESSION['idUsers'];
                $sql = "DELETE FROM userhousecleaninfo WHERE idUsers = $user AND bookingComplete = 'No'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                setcookie($postcode_cookie_name, $postcode, time() + (40000), "/"); //Cookie available for about 10 hours
                header('Location:  booking.php');
                exit();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `DELETE FROM ...`, not `DELETE * FROM ...`.

Comment: That still didn't work. Its weird because the header function is being run but the row isn't getting deleted even though it matches both of the WHERE conditions

Comment: Carefully consider whether permanently erasing data at the user level is really something you want to be doing.

Comment: Do you actually have a Session value called idUsers? Your if statement checks for a Session value called user ID but then your query uses a different value. Is that s typo?

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much. Silly mistake, what can I say. I should've seen that

Comment: Did you check the return value from `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`? Did you try `echo $sql;` to see your SQL statement to ensure it's correct?

Comment: All else aside, your code is prone to sql injection. Please read about it and how it affects the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query seems fine to me but I see there is no logic in using **And** statement. Hope iduser attribute is Unique integer.  Check the you ***idUsers*** attribute also in your table. Besides Sql is case **insensitive**.  You can simply use `DELETE FROM userhousecleaninfo WHERE idUsers = $user` .

Comment: Thanks, however i need to check for both because I'm checking that the user hasn't previously attempted to place a booking which they haven't completed. However if they have previously placed an order i dont want to delete there booking

Comment: can you provide userhousecleaninfo  table schema or sreenshot

Comment: Also the idUsers column is an auto increment int that is set when the user signs up to my site.

Comment: Yes i will but in a screen shot, give me a minute

Answer (score -1):

Not sure is it a solution, but have a try:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM userhousecleaninfo WHERE idUsers = '".$user."' AND bookingComplete = 'No'";
```

P.S. Is your "bookingComplete" in database set to varchar? If it's int - so probably doesn't storing your data into field and getting error.